# C# MongoDB driver serialization - Working with binaries

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I've got a "complex" class which contains a property i want to serialized as a binary :

```
public class MyClassA{
  public MyClassB myClassB {get;set;}
  public MyClassB myClassC {get;set;}
  [BsonIgnore]
  public MyClassB myClassD {get;set;}
  private byte[] myClassDBin {get;set}
}
```

I'd like to keep in RAM only the myClassD object but I would also like to serialize only the myClassDBin object. First condition is easy to achieve in the custructor :

```
public class MyClassA{
  public MyClassB myClassB {get;set;}
  public MyClassB myClassC {get;set;}
  [BsonIgnore]
  public MyClassB myClassD {get;set;}
  private byte[] myClassDBin {get;set}

  [BsonConstructor]
  public MyClassA(MyClassB myClassB, MyClassC myClassC, MyClassDBin[] myClassDBin)
  {
     this.myClassB = myClassB;
     this.myClassC = myClassC;
     this.myClassDBin = myClassBin;
     if(this.myClassDBin != null)
     {
        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(this.myClassDBin))
        {
           this.myClassD = myClassD.Load(stream);//custom serializer
        }
     }
     this.myClassDBin = null; //Keep only one object in RAM
  }
}
```

That works really fine for deserialization, but what about serialization ? If I want myClassDBin to be serialized, I need it to be not null all the time. Do I need to implement a custom serializer ? It could be a long task as the classes myClassB/C/D are large classes, it was easy with the automapper.... Is there an interface just like with XML we can implement to occur just before serialization ?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had to implement the whole serializer, but I read [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/H5fI12GOSg8) from Robert Sam which helped me a lot. I simply wrote a custom serializer as :

```
internal class MesureSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{
  private readonly IBsonSerializer _classMapSerializer;

  public MesureSerializer()
  {
     var classMap = BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(MyClassA));
     _classMapSerializer = new BsonClassMapSerializer(classMap);
  }

  object IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  {
     return _classMapSerializer.Deserialize(bsonReader, nominalType, actualType, options);
  }

  void IBsonSerializer.Serialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  {
     MyClassA item = (MyClassA)value;
     if(item.myClassD != null)
     {
        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
           item.myClassD.Save(item.myClassD, stream);
           mesure.myClassDBin = stream.ToArray();
        }
     }
     else
     {
        item.myClassDBin = null;
     }
     _classMapSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, nominalType, item, options);
     item.myClassDBin = null;
  }


  object IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
  {
     return _classMapSerializer.Deserialize(bsonReader, nominalType, options);
  }

  IBsonSerializationOptions IBsonSerializer.GetDefaultSerializationOptions()
  {
     return _classMapSerializer.GetDefaultSerializationOptions();
  }
}
```

It was as simple as that !